# Are the SATA power connectors on motherboards compatible with both 2.5 & 3.5 drives?

Tags: sata, power-supply-unit

Are the SATA power connectors on motherboards compatible with both 2.5 & 3.5 drives?

I want to switch my desktops internal 3.5 in drives to 2.5 in drives. I know that the signal cables are the same, but does that apply to the power connections too?

Is it safe?

Comment: Possible it would be better to move this question to superuser.

Comment: +vote - and btw, there are no SATA power connectors on motherboards that I've seen - that would be quite interesting though ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection is the same, and the power levels are both the same independently of the disk form-factor (3.5 or 2.5 inch), so it is absolutely safe to connect a 2.5 inch drive to your desktop PC. 
Watch the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) to read more about SATA.

Though,  I've met some drives that had non-standard SATA-connectors (on the HP Pavilion notebook). t has the same pinout, but the different construction.

Comment: Have to second this - in my experience if they are physically compatible then they are logically compatible too - being able to use the same form factor for 2.5" disk connections was one of the stated benefits of SATA.